# How to loop through multiple variables dynamically

Tags: r

I have multiple variables, with similar names, each containing different matrices. I am creating a for loop that I hope to perform that same code over the different matrices, by looping through the variable names.

Here are the set variable names:

```
attr_intrst <- c(4,5,6,7)
test_lvls_4 <- combn(2:3,2)
test_lvls_5 <- combn(1:3,2)
test_lvls_6 <- combn(1:3,2)
test_lvls_7 <- combn(1:5,2)
```

Here is the for loop, I would like to create:

```
for (b in 1:length(attr_intrst)) {
  att_n <- attr_intrst[b]
  test_seq <- seq(2,length(test_lvls_4),2)
}
```

Where it says, "test_lvls_4" I'm imagining it would say "test_lvls_b" where b is the value that comes from attr_intrst. Is there a way to loop through variables like this? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to get the objects into a `list` `mget(ls(pattern = "^test_lvls_\\d+$"))`

Comment: Ah, I will try a list, thank you! The att_n is used in a subsequent for loop for a function.

Comment: Your expected output is not clear to me